# React with Chrome : big pre tag with monospace code

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome

In my react app, I have a big piece of generated code (110k lines) to show on screen (an openapi json spec). I wrapped it in a `<pre>` tag with:

```
overflow-y: scroll;
word-wrap: break-word;
white-space: pre-wrap;
font-family: monospace;
height: 100%;
```

This `<pre>` has a parent `<div>` which set the height to something like 800px so it can scroll.

This used to work well, but recently chrome hang completely when displaying it. It works on Brave and Firefox without any issues. Strangely, the code is shared on server, if I type the url of the server and display the code directly (no react, just basic code display), chrome behave normally. It automatically wrap the code in a `<pre>` just like I do, with the same css style, except for the height:100%; I wonder what the hang in my application all of a sudden.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can maybe render it as a [virtualised list](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized) with the content: `<pre>line1</pre><pre>line2</pre>`. Rendering over 100k lines of content seems a bit much, especially because the user can't see most of it.

Comment: Not a bad idea, we already have react virtualized in our lib I think. Should be easy enough. I just wonder why chrome is so bad at handling this.

Comment: Maybe Chrome is not efficiently rendering this (rendering hidden lines as well). It may just be a bug introduced that will be fixed in a later version. Either way, you can't fix Chrome for every Chrome user. Using virtualized will make CTRL + F search more complicated since the browser now no longer has all the content.

Comment: True, but I don't need search, so good enough. It just to give them a preview, because you can generate the openapi spec with different parameters. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Used react-virtualized list with chunks of data. Not ideal, but good enough for our purpose.